# How to load a table in a tab-pane div with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this tab-pane

```
<div class="tab-pane py-2 fade active show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab" data-id="1" id="instrument-1">1</div>
<div class="tab-pane py-2 fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab" data-id="3" id="instrument-3">3</div>
<div class="tab-pane py-2 fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab" data-id="4" id="instrument-4">4</div>
```

And i want to know how to load the same table with different content in each of this divs with javascript.

this is the table:

```
<table class="table table-responsive" id="tablaBitacoras" role="tabpanel">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
          <th scope="col">Nombre Estudiante</th>
          <th scope="col">Profesor Encargado</th>
          <th scope="col">Instrumento</th>
          <th scope="col">Bitacora</th>
        </tr>
      </thead >
      <tbody >
        <tr id="trClone">
          <th scope="row" id="fecha">Nose</th>
          <td id="estudiante">aksdj</td>
          <td id="profesor">asdas</td>
          <td id="instrumento">adssa</td>
          <td id="bitacora">asdasdasd</td>
        </tr>  
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: How you are managing the content of table? are you getting content from ajax request or you are fetching it from database on page load?

Comment: Im using ajax request

Comment: can you please show the format of ajax data response. I mean what kind of data show are getting in response.

Comment: I Solved my problem thanks for answer